# Golang how can I guarantee data finishes in a goroutine while being accessed by another goroutine

Tags: go

Hi guys I am trying to make a party system using websockets where people can enter a queue and then get matched with 5 people similar to them. Right now I'm having trouble with this part:

```
type PartyHub struct {
    Partys             map[string]*Party
    PartialPartys      []*PartialParty
    Queue              []*Member
    AddParty           chan *Party
    RemoveParty        chan *Party
    AddPartialParty    chan *PartialParty
    RemovePartialParty chan *PartialParty
    EnterQueue         chan *Member
    LeaveQueue         chan *Member
    Mu                 sync.Mutex
}
// Run will begin monitoring the channels
// to register and unregister partys as they are
// created or destroyed
func (p *PartyHub) Run() {
    for {
        select {
        case member := <-p.EnterQueue:
            go p.SortMemberIntoParty(member)
            go p.SortMemberIntoParty(member)
            go p.SortMemberIntoParty(member)
            go p.SortMemberIntoParty(member)
            go p.SortMemberIntoParty(member)

            log.Println(p.PartialPartys)
        case party := <-p.AddPartialParty:
            p.Mu.Lock()
            defer p.Mu.Unlock()
            p.PartialPartys = append(p.PartialPartys, party)
        }
    }
}

// SortMemberIntoParty will take a new user entering the queue and find an appropriate Party
// for the member to join, taking into account RankTollerance, Rank
func (p *PartyHub) SortMemberIntoParty(member *Member) {
    p.Mu.Lock()
    defer p.Mu.Unlock()
    if len(p.PartialPartys) == 0 {
        log.Println("Here")
        newParty := &PartialParty{Accepting: true, Members: []*Member{member}}
        p.AddPartialParty <- newParty
        return
    }

    foundPartyForMember := false
    for _, party := range p.PartialPartys {
        goodFitForParty := true
        for _, partyMember := range party.Members {
            log.Println(member.Type == partyMember.Type, member.Rank >= partyMember.Rank-partyMember.RankTol, member.Rank <= partyMember.Rank+partyMember.RankTol)
            if member.Type == partyMember.Type && member.Rank >= partyMember.Rank-partyMember.RankTol && member.Rank <= partyMember.Rank+partyMember.RankTol {

                goodFitForParty = true
                continue
            } else {
                goodFitForParty = false
                break
            }
        }

        if !goodFitForParty {
            continue
        } else {
            foundPartyForMember = true
            party.Mu.Lock()
            defer party.Mu.Unlock()
            party.Members = append(party.Members, member)
            if len(party.Members) == 5 {
                party.Accepting = false
                go party.SendReadyCheck()
            }
            break
        }
    }


    if !foundPartyForMember {
        newParty := &PartialParty{Accepting: true, Members: []*Member{member}}
        p.AddPartialParty <- newParty
    }

    log.Println("Sorting Members")
}
```

The only problem is, the 5 `goroutines` seem to finish quicker than the data knows what happened.

For example: `p.PartialPartys` says it has no parties.

What I need is to have `p.PartialPartys` always up to date for every `goroutine` that accesses that field of the `PartyHub` struct I though the `sync.Mutex` would do this for me but it doesn't seem to be the case, can anybody tell me the best way to keep all my goroutines in sync with the same data?

Comment: I haven't looked through all your code but at least the following seems wrong: `defer p.Mu.Unlock()` in `Run` will run when `Run` function returns (I doubt this is what you want), you start 5 go routines but they run sequentially (because of mutex), one goroutine will be enough and will make your code simpler. I would suggest you to think how to implement the required functionality using less goroutines and channels, the code is very hard to follow as it is.

Comment: @kostya I have 5 goroutines at the moment for my own debugging because I don't have access to 5 computers to simulate 5 people entering a queue so I just add the same person 5 times at the moment, when its done there will be the one goroutine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So with this implementation, none of your five goroutines are going to be be able to run in parallel because they are all trying to acquite the `p.Mu` mutex.  And looking at the way you're using the `p.AddPartialParty` channel, I wouldn't be surprised if the code can deadlock.

Consider the following sequence of events:

1. One of the `SortMemberIntoParty` goroutines starts running and acquires the mutex.
2. It sends a value on `p.AddPartialParty`, which is received by `Run`.  `Run` then tries to acquire the mutex, so blocks.
3. The original `SortMemberIntoParty` goroutine completes and releases the mutex.
4. A different `SortMemberIntoParty` goroutine acquires the mutex, and tries to send another value to `p.AddPartialParty`.
5. The goroutine blocks because there is no one ready to read the value (`Run` is still waiting on the mutex before it gets back to the `select` statement).

So now you've got a blocked goroutine holding a lock needed by the receiving end of the channel.  Also note that at (4) you won't see the new `PartialParty` because `Run` hasn't managed to add it yet.

If you do need the mutex, then it might be easier to just have your `SortMemberIntoParty` goroutine update `p.PartialPartys` directly rather than using the channel: you already know that no one else will be accessing the variable concurrently.

It's also worth remembering that this mutex essentially means that all `SortMemberIntoParty` goroutines will be serialised.  If you were using goroutines in the hope of achieving parallelism here, the mutex defeats that.

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed response, if you could suggest a better way to do this, using channels, and not a mutex that would be great, this is only a small part of my party system so I need to keep the channels

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.  With the design you currently have, having a single goroutine dedicated to allocating players to parties might be enough.  If it doesn't scale, you could try partitioning the players before allocating them to parties.  With your existing code, you could try doing that based on the `Type`, or by dividing the ranks.